# Why are the bandsmen wearing black masks in The Last Emperor?

Tags: realism, the-last-emperor

In a scene in ***the Last Emperor***, when Puyi is singing *'[Am I blue?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Am_I_Blue%3F)'*, all members of his music band are Europeans but wearing black masks.

**Why?**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This European band is made up in '[blackface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackface#:%7E:text=Blackface%20is%20the%20practice%20of,of%20a%201900%20William%20H.)' (e.g. black pancake makeup intended to simulate black skin). At the end of this clip you can hear them playing jazz, suggesting that this is a jazz-*themed* event with the band '*blacked up*' to parody African-American jazz musicians, as was common at the time.

The source novel states that this is an "*English 'country club'*". Presumably the band didn't wear their makeup and played more sedate music during the daytime.

> There was a “Country Club” in Tientsin run by the English, a very
> grand establishment where only the foreign bosses were allowed to set
> foot, Chinese being absolutely forbidden to pass the main entrance. I
> was the only exception to this rule.* I was allowed to enter freely
> and even to take members of my household, and we all enjoyed the
> delights of being “special Chinese”.
>
> <sub><sup>[From Emperor to Citizen by Pu Yi Aisin-Gioro](https://www.goodreads.com/en/book/show/688549)</sup></sub>

Comment: Oh my gosh, well done on resurrecting this question - I am surprised that no-one answered it earlier since blackface and minstrel shows were common at one point. I'm old enough to remember minstrel shows on TV in the UK (and being young enough to find them extremely dull).

Comment: @iandotkelly - I'm munching my way through the pile of 'unanswered' questions to see if there are any that can be resolved simply